# It's possible to integrate Python with Java?

Tags: java, python, integration, nltk

I have a main application that is coded with Java, but I want to use Python because the NLTK lib.

I want to know if it's possible do some integration with these two languages. Thinks like passing parameters from Java to Python and retrieving processed data from Python to Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Python Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)

From their [FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo) site:

> **What is Jython?**
>
> Jython is the successor to JPython. The Jython project was created in
>   accordance with the CNRI JPython 1.1.x license, in order to ensure the
>   continued existence and development of this important piece of Python
>   software. The intent is to manage this project with the same open
>   policies that are serving CPython so well.
>
> **What is JPython?**
>
> JPython is an implementation of the Python programming language which
>   is designed to run on the Java(tm) Platform.