# how to design a price checking webapp in play framework combine with python scripting?

Tags: java, web-services, model-view-controller, architecture, playframework

```
My goal is
```

To let user enter a shopping site link in my webapp, For example, amazon.com/items/123, and then according to the price I crawled from the amazon.com for this item  123, then I (do some logic stuffs) generate a competitive price for this item and display in my webapp.

```
What I have is :
```

The python script can goto the amazon.com/items/[input]  , and then crawl the price ,item , etc details,

The simple user interface that allow user to enter a link with a controller doing nothing..

```
What I dont know is
```

how to combine the user interface in play-framework and the python script?
Or is there any better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Is rewriting the python script in Scala an option?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not related to Play Framework.

There are ways to run Python from Java: [Java Python Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration) . But that would be a mess to maintain.

Your parser does not seem to be a complicated one. I would rewrite in on Java. Plat itself provides a nice WS library for asynchronous HTTP calls: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1-RC2/JavaWS