# How does Spark interoperate with CPython

Tags: scala, pandas, apache-spark, interop, pyspark

I have an Akka system written in `scala` that needs to call out to some `Python` code, relying on `Pandas` and `Numpy`, so I can't just use Jython. I noticed that Spark uses CPython on its worker nodes, so I'm curious how it executes Python code and whether that code exists in some re-usable form.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PySpark architecture is described here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals.

[image: PySpark internals]

As @Holden said Spark uses py4j to access Java objects in JVM from the python. But this is only one case - when driver program is written in python (left part of diagram there)

The other case (the right part of the diagram) - when Spark Worker starts Python process and sends serialized Java objects to python program to be processed, and receives output. Java objects are serialized into pickle format - so python could read them.

Looks like what you are looking for is the latter case. Here some links to the Spark's scala core that could be useful for you to get started:

- [Pyrolite](https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite/) library that provides Java  interface to Python's pickle protocols - used by Spark to serialize Java objects into pickle format. For example such conversion is required for accessing Key part of Key, Value pairs for the PairRDD.
- Scala code that starts python process and iterates with it: [api/python/PythonRDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/74fdc97c7206c6d715f128ef7c46055e0bb90760/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonRDD.scala)
- SerDeser utils that do picking of the code: [api/python/SerDeUtil.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9b16e67c636a8a91ab9fb0f4ef98146abbde1e9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/SerDeUtil.scala)
- Python side: [python/pyspark/worker.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/32fbd297dd651ba3ce4ce52aeb0488233149cdf9/python/pyspark/worker.py)

Answer (score 5):

So Spark uses py4j to communicate between the JVM and Python. This allow Spark to work with different versions of Python but requires serializing data from the JVM and vice versa to communicate. There is more info on py4j at http://py4j.sourceforge.net/ , hope that helps :)