# Integrate python libraries with android to use them on Java

Tags: java, android, python, android-ndk

I want to make an app which is purely based on AI-based functionality, and I'd like to use some python libraries for that (looking mostly at natural language processing and deep learning). Now, I know there are tools (kivy, NDK) to I can use to develop the app entirely in python, but I really want to develop the app using JAVA.

How can I make an android app with JAVA, while still using some python libraries?

Comment: if you can't answer the question ,kindly don't vote it negative.

Comment: Which AI packages in Python are you using. Surely there are Java equivalents.

Comment: i don't know yet , but i think some natural learning processing(NLP) and deep learning algorithms libraries in python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Python Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration)

Comment: You should look into Deeplearning4j for DL libs in Java: http://deeplearning4j.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general approach, you could use Android Studio, which employs Java and XML files, to build your app, and tie that app to python-powered RESTful web services on a back end. [Eve](http://python-eve.org/) is an open-source Python REST API framework which would allow for this.