# Call Scala & Spark code from Python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have a codebase written in Scala that uses Spark. I'd like the method `foo` to be called externally from Python code.

```
def foo(a: Int, b: String): String
```

I saw here [Java Python Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration) that I can use Jython. It think that's an overkill though.

Can't I add a PySpark method that wraps the Scala/Spark existing method?

If not, isn't there a simpler solution, where I wouldn't need a special module like Jython?

Comment: Method to do what exactly? Or if you prefer where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Java/Scala function from an action or a transformation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684842/how-to-use-java-scala-function-from-an-action-or-a-transformation)