# How to use python in a java project

Tags: java, python, api

I hope that I'm in the right place

I have a java project and I want to use some methods of a python project from Github

This is it: 
https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza

I want to pass a String parameter to a method of the python project I've searched for a way but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Python Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration)

Comment: It's too old...

Comment: @FALCAOINMADRID Did you look at all of the answers? Many are newer than the question and talk about tools like [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/).