# Eclipse plugin - how to run external class

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to make a plugin for Eclipse. The thing is that I looked into the API, and examples, and I managed to make a button on main bar, with a specific icon, and when I click it, open up an InputDialog.

The hard part, is that I want to start an aplication from this button, but not with Runtime as it was a new process. I simply want to start a class inside plugin, which will log in to a server and get some output from it. I want it to be opened in a console, like launching a normal application, or a separate console.

The best example of this kind is a Tomcat plugin which starts Tomcat, and then outputs the console to the Eclipse console. I want to do that too.  I've looked at the Tomcat source plugin, but I got stuck there too. They use their own launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "I want to simply start a class". I assume there is a command line tool that you want to execute and redirect its output to the console window.

To be able to do that without spawning a new process, you have to be able to control the output stream of the tool. If it cannot be controlled, then you have no choice but to start a new process to properly capture the tool's output.

It is technically possible to call `System.setOut` instead, but it will redirect output from all threads to your console which is not what you want.

Nevertheless you start by creating a console:

```java
// function findConsole copied from:
// http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F
private MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
    for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
       if (name.equals(existing[i].getName()))
          return (MessageConsole) existing[i];
    //No console found, so create a new one.
    MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[]{myConsole});
    return myConsole;
}

// Find my console
MessageConsole cons = findConsole("MyTool Console");
MessageConsoleStream out = cons.newMessageStream();

// Optionally get it's input stream so user can interact with my tool
IOConsoleInputStream in = cons.getInputStream();

// Optionally make a differently coloured error stream
MessageConsoleStream err = cons.newMessageStream();
err.setColor(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

// Display the console.
// Obtain the active page. See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_the_active_workbench_page%3F
IWorkbenchPage page = ...;
String id = IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW;
IConsoleView view = (IConsoleView) page.showView(id);
view.display(cons);
```

Then set the input and output streams of my tool and start processing in a different thread so the UI will not block.

```java
// Create my tool and redirect its output
final MyTool myTool = new MyTool();
myTool.setOutputStream(out);
myTool.setErrorStream(err);
myTool.setInputStream(in);

// Start it in another thread
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myTool.startExecuting();
    }
});
t.start();
```

If your tool does not support I/O redirection, you have no choice but to start it in another process with the `ProcessBuilder` and use a number of threads to move data between console and process streams See: `Process.getInputStream()`, `Process.getOutputStream()` and `Process.getErrorStream()`.

The following links have additional useful details:

- *[Executing a Java application in a separate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636367/java-executing-a-java-application-in-a-separate-process)*
- *[FAQ How do I write to the console from a plug-in?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F)*
- *[FAQ How do I find the active workbench page?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_the_active_workbench_page%3F)*

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for running a new console with controls, like stop delete, and deleteAll! This is what I asked for in the beginning, but the message console is good to know!

```
ILaunchConfigurationType launchType = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfigurationType("org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication");
ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy config = null;
try {
    config = launchType.newInstance(null, "My Plugin working");
} catch (CoreException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
config.setAttribute(ILaunchConfiguration.ATTR_SOURCE_LOCATOR_ID, "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceLocator.JavaSourceLookupDirector");
String[] classpath = new String[] { "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\myjr.jar" };
ArrayList classpathMementos = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < classpath.length; i++) {
    IRuntimeClasspathEntry cpEntry = JavaRuntime.newArchiveRuntimeClasspathEntry(new Path(classpath[i]));
    cpEntry.setClasspathProperty(IRuntimeClasspathEntry.USER_CLASSES);
    try {
        classpathMementos.add(cpEntry.getMemento());
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
config.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_DEFAULT_CLASSPATH, false);
config.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_CLASSPATH, classpathMementos);
config.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_MAIN_TYPE_NAME, "collectorlog.handlers.MyClass");
try {
    ILAUNCH = config.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null);
} catch (CoreException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```