# New JVM Process for a class

Tags: java, process, jvm

I have a java application which has a JTabbedPane in a JFrame.

I want to simulate the firefox tabs. When you run an applet, it somehow starts a new process for that applet and when you kill the tab, the process dies. I want to do this for component class.

Currently I have:

```
package pkgmessaging;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final JTabbedPane TabPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private ArrayList<Message> Messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public Frame() {
        this.add(TabPane);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void addMessage() {
        //Message is a JPanel that holds other components.
        Message C = new Message();  //Some how create this in a new Process/JVM and add it to my JTabbedPane.


        this.Messages.add(C);
        this.addTab(TabPane, "One", C);
        this.pack();
    }

    private void addTab(final String Title, final Component component) {
        //To other stuff here..

        CloseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                synchronized (Frame.this.TabPane) {
                    TabPane.remove(component);

                    //Some how close the process/jvm here.
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So how can I run a class in a new process/jvm and add it to my JTabbedPane? Do I need JNI? If so, what would I be looking at? I just need to know where to look and how to start.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Because I want to learn how firefox tabs works and I want to implement my own in a sort of browser application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing a Java application in a separate process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636367/executing-a-java-application-in-a-separate-process)

Comment: ^No because that doesn't show how to add the component or application to a Tab.