# How to start/stop java application during junit integration test

Tags: java, junit

I have done a fair amount of research and don't see a good way to do this. I have a java application that has integration tests. For the sake of the integration tests, the tests need to start the actual application. This is done like so in each junit test.

```
@BeforeClass
final public static void setup() {
    Application.main(new String[]{});
}
```

How do I shut down the application though? I notice it stays around as rogue process after the junit tests shutdown. In addition I have done this with springboot before and am aware that springboot provides annotations. We cannot use springboot though for this. So i need to find a non spring way. How do I shut down the application in a junit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this with Gradle 6.3 and JUnit 5; I briefly see a `[java] <defunct>` process in the `ps` output, and that disappears on its own. Maybe it's because I only run a single test suite and when you run more you'd need to cleanup after each.

That said, look into the [Java process API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). Start the app as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636367/executing-a-java-application-in-a-separate-process), but hold on to the `Process` returned from `ProcessBuilder.start()` and call its `destroy()` method in your `@AfterClass` method.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

public class DemoApplicationTests {
    private static Process process;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add(System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java"); // quick and dirty for unix
        command.add("-cp");
        command.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        command.add(DemoApplication.class.getName());

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        process = builder.inheritIO().start();
    }

    @Test
    void whatever() {
        // ...
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterClass() {
        process.destroy();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah my mind is a little blown right now ... Im going to mark this with a green checkmark, but I would really be interested if anybody else has solutions to this. Thanks.

Comment: This is a solid answer and I got this working. However I noticed afterwards I didn't actually need to do this. The reason being that if you start the application with Appliation.main() ... It will start and stop within the junit tests. I was mislead because when I was looking at the processes. When starting the integration tests, I noticed 2 would start up and 1 would remain after. I assumed this was the one that was started with Application.main() ... When I executed the other junit tests though, i notice that they too start a process that is not terminated after the tests are done ‍♂️.