# "Simulate" an external program reading/holding on to a file, preventing File#delete()

Tags: java, file, filelock

I am [currently looking into an issue with Logback](https://github.com/fatso83/logback-bug) where the Compressor class is unable to delete a file if I open it in the log file reader [glogg](https://glogg.bonnefon.org/). This situation only happens with that program, should I open the file in Notepad.exe no issues arise, so it is somehow related to locking the file or something like that (full reproduction steps exist in the [linked repo](https://github.com/fatso83/logback-bug)).

Right now, I need to manually open the glogg program to reproduce the issue, but ideally I would like to just reproduce this using the Java demo program. So far, I have been quite unsuccessful. So I would like to know how to achieve the following:

- Start thread A and thread B
- thread A should write to file X
- when Thread A is doing `File#delete()` on X it should return `false` (meaning unsuccessful)
- thread B should be the reason for this as it holds on to the file somehow, preventing the delete from being successful

### What I have tried out

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        logDumper.debug(bigString);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] s) {

    final Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
            var fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("./test.log");
            var file = new File("./test.log");
            fileInputStream.readAllBytes();
            System.out.println("Size: " + file.length());
            final var fc = fileInputStream.getChannel();

            // this entire locking thing does not seem to have any effect
            final var shared = true; // required to avoid throwing when opening a file as read-only
            try (FileLock lock = fc.tryLock(0,file.length(), shared)) {
            } catch (NonReadableChannelException| NonWritableChannelException e) {
                logger.error("Something happened", e);
                fc.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Crashed on locking", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    new Thread(runnable).start();
    new Main().run();
}
```

Comment: @Kayaman I have basically just tinkered around with the reproduction case code in the linked repository. I have just added one such attempt in the question above, where I try to make one thread lock the file, but it seems it can be deleted regardless. The deletion is implicit, as it is done by the `Compressor` class in Logback, after compressing the file. I have not tried opening a RandomAccessFile, as I wanted to work backwards from a working real-world reproduction towards a Java-only reproduction with no manual steps.

Comment: "File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine".  From : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html. However, this seems to be an example how to work around it: https://gist.github.com/syazawa/d1f6bf4553dcc469709b

Comment: @OliverJanKrylow One workaround I could think of then is to simply spin up a second JVM process from the first one. For instance a single class that just opens a file and does not close it. Got some good pointers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636367/executing-a-java-application-in-a-separate-process. That would not simulate, though, it would actually _be_ a second program.

Comment: That is probably your best bet. Even if you achieve a file lock between threads in one JVM, like the example I posted, I am beginning to doubt that it would be useful in your case. Since your goal is a regression test, it should simulate the original bug condition as closely as possible. A second process is therefore probably better. Then you "only" have to deal with OS platform differences in regards to file locking.